# How to pass arguments, a parent class "B" id, when create() of factory is called from rspec, for a child class A?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I need to write a rspec test.I have child-parent instance variables who were created with the factory create method somehow. Now, I need to create another child, of the same parent.

i have called create(:class_a, id: class_b.id)

Answer (score 0):

From the tag, and the context, I'm going to assume you are using factory-bot. If your factories are correct, your test might look something like this (I'm going to rename your models 'parent' and 'kid'):

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Parent, type: :model do
  let(:parent) { create(:parent) }
  let!(:kid1) { create(:kid, parent_id: parent.id) }
  let!(:kid2) { create(:kid, parent_id: parent.id) }

  it 'is has 2 children' do
    expect(parent.kids.length).to eq(2)
    expect(kid1[:parent_id]).to eq(parent.id)
  end
end
```

The first let statement creates an instance of parent, but only after the variable 'parent' is used somewhere in the test. The second and third let statements create 2 different instances of the kid class named 'kid1' and 'kid2'. Notice the ! after the let statement? That means create the kids right aways. And when the kids are created, the parent is created too, because the 'parent' variable is used when creating the kids.

Now you can write tests like the one in within the it block.